# Jetty: load a server bean from war before initialization

Tags: authentication, web-applications, jetty

I have a webapp being loaded from a Jetty server.

I want to load a bean implementing a `MappedLoginService` inside the webapp (not from the server) before the webapp starts loading.

Is there any way?

I tried to load the bean in the webapp post-construct and in webapp application class (`javax.ws.rs.Application`), without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the initialization in the `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` file.

That will load it during WebApp initialization, before the Servlet layer initialization kicks off.

Comment: Thanks! I extended the answer with a jetty-web.xml example for running some code.

Answer (score 0):

I follow Joakim answer creating a `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` file and it worked. I just want to extend the answer adding a sample jetty-web.xml that prints something before servlet is initiated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="context" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Get class="java.lang.System" name="out">
      <Call name="println">
         <Arg>Hello world!</Arg>
      </Call>
   </Get>
</Configure>
```

More information about jetty-web.xml syntax [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax).